# How to get table names as seen in SQL database with SSAS DMV/MDX query

Tags: sql-server, database, ssas

I'm trying to build a report off the cubes we've built in SSAS, and I've found this [documentation for DMV and MDX queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/schema-rowsets/ole-db-olap/ole-db-for-olap-schema-rowsets), but I can't find what I want. It can return the dimension names as seen in SSAS, but I want the table name as seen in SQL Server, i.e. if we have a table called `billingLocation` in the database I want that instead of `Billing Location` which is how it's seen in SSAS. Is this possible?

As an aside, can you pull fact tables from the same query type? I only see information about pulling dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late but you can use LEFT(Column_Name,X) to get some characters. Could be useful

Answer (score 0):

There is not an existed DMV in SSAS to load the dsv name of a measure group or dimension which related Cube schema. I think you have to create a program and connect to SSAS server with AMO.NET to get these information by yourself.

But there is an IDE to get these info and allow you to export to excel, it is not free(30 days free trial): MDXHelper, www.mdx-helper.com.

Hope this help you. Thanks.